# Gatsbyjs, how to make build cmd use cached previously generated static files?

Tags: gatsby

I've got a CD/CI pipeline that been optimized to reduce the process build time. There's a stage job or task, that runs the Gatsbyjs build command (gatsby build), where it outputs the built static files into a public directory. Assuming that the application is a CMS and has a growing number of Blog articles, and each Article has "n" translations, the process is going to be quite long!

Currently, the gatsby documentation doesn't seem to provide any details about it, so it's currently not supported I believe; I do remember seeing in the past (not hot in the subject at the moment, as I've built the UI some time ago), but Gatsbyjs uses a webpack plugin to generate the static files (afaik), so maybe someone knows a method around this?
At the moment, I have the CI/CD UI Stage doing a "sync" to the destination s3 bucket, only updating what diffs, but would be way better to skip matches.

If no feedback on this and you are reading this in the future, feel free to drop a comment as I might have worked in a plugin or a solution for this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such tool yet, and after contacting the Gatsby support team they mentioned they are going to release a Cloud service that does incremental builds in a few months.